# coldfusion documents outside of root folder

Tags: coldfusion

I am in the process of rewriting our websites and I have taken advantage of Coldfusion mappings to move my cfc files outside the root directory. I would like to do the same for documents (especially ones download to us) but it appears mapping won't work for that? Is there another way?

Comment: Right, you never want to upload files under your web root. And as you found, mappings are not used for this. It's just part of your upload process to write the files to a specific directory. See the documentation from Learn CF in a Week - [File Upoads](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/File_Uploads/) The user that the ColdFusion process runs under will need access to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to make your uploads available for viewing, in which case they need to be accessible by the webserver. I typically upload to a temp directory for processing, and then move the file to a permanent location, which is outside of my public webroot (www folder?), but mapped in the webserver so that the files can be served. I do this to keep source code completely separate from user generated content.

So a simplified directory structure might look like this:

```
/www
/cfc
/data
/data/temp
/data/user
```

As you've already figured out, your cfcs can be accessed via a mapping. Then, depending on your web server, you would make the data directory available, and lock down the kinds of files you want to serve via your web server.